# Node js - How to check if Redis server is available

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

I have several instances of redis. i want to switch in between the instances, if some instance is down ? Can anyone suggest some way to check whether the redis server is available or not.
And i am not using ioredis package, i am using redis package only.

Also is there any check like ping command in node.js

Comment: If you don't already have a connection, then you [connect](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis?_ga=2.81986134.1763940340.1625722177-357248129.1622353851#api) to it and watch for the `ready` or `connect` event or `error` .   If you already have a connection, there is a [ping](https://redis.io/commands/ping).

Comment: need to check with code, not from terminal.

Comment: Well, you did NOT show what library you're using to access redis (there are many).  The point of the above comment is that the capability exists and you have to see how to use it in whatever library you're using.  Next step is up to you.